Is NSPACE(n) stricly contained in TIME(2^n^2)?
We got this question in a Complexity course test and I'm not sure whether this statement holds or not...
I would love to get your opinion on it.

Hint: what is a smallest TIME(...) class that you can show to contain NSPACE(n)?
